# google apps script web app call differents functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 2 functions that return different JSON, but when I hit deploy it always returns the JSON of the main function how to access the 2n functions

```
//function 1


function doGet(){ // Open Google Sheet using ID var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");

// Get all values in active sheet var values = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(); var data = [];

// Iterate values in descending order for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

// Get each row
var row = values[i];

// Create object
var feedback = {};

feedback['name'] = row[0];
feedback['es'] = row[1];
feedback['en'] = row[2];

// Push each row object in data
data.push(feedback);

}

// Return result return ContentService .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)) .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); }

//function 2

function myFunction() { // Open Google Sheet using ID var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");

// Get all values in active sheet var sheetProduct = sheet.getSheetByName('Productos') var values = sheetProduct.getDataRange().getValues(); var data = [];

// Iterate values in descending order for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
// Get each row
var row = values[i];

// Create object
var feedback = {};

feedback['name'] = row[0];
feedback['es'] = row[1];
feedback['en'] = row[2];

// Push each row object in data
data.push(feedback);
}

// Return result return ContentService .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data)) .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); }
```

I need call when deploy two functions

I clicked deploy and thought that the URL returned could be added to what function to call.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I thought that there are several methods.

### Pattern 1:

If you want to achieve your goal by each URL for each function, how about the following method?

#### 1. Prepare 1st sample script.

Please set one of your 2 functions to `doGet`.

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok1"); // This is a simple sample.
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps as a new version.

Deploy Web Apps as a new version and retrieve the Web Apps URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId1}/exec`.

#### 3. Prepare 2nd sample script.

Please set another of your 2 functions to `doGet`.

```
function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok2"); // This is a simple sample.
}
```

#### 4. Deploy Web Apps as a new version.

Deploy Web Apps as a new version and retrieve the Web Apps URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId2}/exec`.

#### 5. Testing.

By this flow, you can retrieve 2 Web Apps URLs as follows.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId1}/exec

https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId2}/exec
```

In this case, you can use one of your 2 functions by the endpoint. For example,

- When `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId1}/exec` is accessed, `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok1")` is run.
- When `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId2}/exec` is accessed, `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok2")` is run.

### Pattern 2:

If you can achieve your goal using the query parameter, how about the following method?

#### 1. Prepare sample script.

```
function doGet(e) {
  const functionName = e.parameter.functionName;
  if (functionName == "function1") {
    return function1();
  } else if (functionName == "function2") {
    return function2();
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("No function name.");
}

function function1() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok1"); // This is a simple sample.
}
function function2() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok2"); // This is a simple sample.
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps as a new version.

Deploy Web Apps as a new version and retrieve the Web Apps URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec`.

#### 3. Testing.

In this case,

- When `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec?functionName=function1` is accessed, `function1()` is run.
- When `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec?functionName=function2` is accessed, `function2()` is run.

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".